# Rewrite URL Structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to change the URL structure of my site. My current URL structure is like this:

```
www.domain.com/events/events.php?location=san%20francisco
```

I want to change the URL structure to:

```
www.domain.com/events/san-francisco
```

My XMPL site map has the URLs listed like the first example. I want the search engines to index the URL like the second example. What are all the things I need to do to achieve this? The {city} in the location parameter is dynamic depending on the user's IP address. Do I need to change my XML sitemap to list new URL structure? What do I need to put in my `.htaccess` file. Do I need to change the actual URLs links on my website to the new structure or can I just use `.htaccess?`

Comment: Does your PHP accept `www.domain.com/events/events.php?location=san-francisco` instead of `%20` or are you able to add that functionality? If you can add that then it will be easy to do what you want if you can't then it will use a lot of server resource doing the conversion from `%20` to dash and might not be worth if you're hosted on a shared server.

Comment: @prix yes it does accept san-Francisco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /events\.php\?location=(.*)%20(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /events/%2-%3\? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^events/(.*)$ /events.php?location=$1 [L]
```

Changing `R=302` to `R=301` when you know it redirect correctly

EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(.*)/(.*)\.php\?location=(.*)%20(.*)&lid=(.*)&slid=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%3/%4-%5/%6/%7\? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/$1.php?location=$2&lid=$3&slid=$4 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(.*)/(.*)\.php\?location=(.*)%20(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%3/%4-%5\? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /$1/$1.php?location=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what about for my pages nightclubs/nightclubs.php and photos/photos.php ? Is there a general rewriterule that I can use for all pages or will I have to create a rule for each page?

Comment: is the parameter `?location=` with them as well?

Comment: Yes location parameter is with them. Here is another variation. Can you please give me the general rule for this example. Nightclubs/nightclubs.php?location=San%20francisco&lid=1234&slid=5678 . And also how do I make it change San%20francisco to San-francisco ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a .htaccess file similar to the one below. It will match fancy URL and forward the request to the right php file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)$ /$1/$1.php?location=$2
```

With this, both www.domain.com/events/events.php?location=san%20francisco and www.domain.com/events/san-francisco will lead to the same page.

But if you don't change your sitemap nor the links on your site, search engines won't know that.
You have then 2 solutions :

- change all your links in your site and sitemap with the new structure URL
- use a redirect rule to redirect "old" pages to the "new" ones

From what I know about SEO, the first option is the best. Or even better, a combination of both solutions : change all your links, and use a redirect 301 rule so pages already indexed by search engines will not lost their ranking and to avoid duplicate content.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*).php?location=(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1/$3 [R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what about for my pages nightclubs/nightclubs.php and photos/photos.php ? Is there a general rewriterule that I can use for all pages or will I have to create a rule for each page?

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. Here is another variation. Can you please give me the general rule for this example. Nightclubs/nightclubs.php?location=San%20francisco&lid=1234&slid=5678 . And also how do I make it change San%20francisco to San-francisco ? Sorry for all the additional questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What rewrited URL do you want for Nightclubs/nightclubs.php?location=San%20francisco&lid=1234&slid=5678 ?
And to change San%20francisco, this should be done directly in your site with PHP or whatever language you are using.
If you want to make a redirection anyway, you can do :

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)%20(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1/$2-$3 [R=301]

But you will a redirection chain : www.domain.com/events/events.php?location=san%20francisco --> www.domain.com/events/san%20francisco --> www.domain.com/events/san-francisco

Comment: This is the rewrites url that I want: Nightclubs/san-francisco/1234/5678

Comment: RewriteEngine On
# Rule 1 for simple URL without IDs
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)$ /$1/$1.php?location=$2
# Rule 2 for URL with lid and slid
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /$1/$1.php?location=$2&lid=$3&slid=$4